# Binding datatable to a rdlc report

Tags: c#, rdlc

I would like to bind `datatable` to a `rdlc` report.

- But name of my `datatable` field includes special letters e.g.
  `avg(%)`
- I can't change the field name.
- I can't set same field name in `xsd.file`
- The field name in `xsd.file` different from field name in `dataTable`.

Therefore, I couldn't bind `datatable` to a `rdlc` report.

The following is my code:

```
LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
report.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("name"), name));
... (???)
report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Student", dt as DataTable));
```

Please help me out.

Comment: XSD file doesn't allow special characters in `name` attribute as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356101/can-we-use-special-character-in-xml-schema-element-name). I believe renaming fields in the database and removing the special characters is the only route.

Comment: Use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string);  The rdlc is html and this will convert special characters.

Comment: unfortunately I can't remove the special characters...

Comment: Is there any solution in cs file ??? like binding the field name each other...

Comment: I didn't say remove.  The code convert special characters.  See wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references,  The utility does the conversion

Comment: i'm sorry about that.. i misunderstood.... but i can't still understand.. where can i use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string)??